# selenium python can't scrape video url

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape vidro url from this [page](https://grabagun.com/firearms/handguns/semi-automatic-handguns/glock-19-gen-5-polished-nickel-9mm-4-02-inch-barrel-15-rounds-exclusive.html). see the picture below

[image]

but the video element div are not showing on selenium chrome browser and I also tried Firefox.

here is my code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromiumService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType

from selenium_stealth import stealth
import requests, csv, time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,service=ChromiumService(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()))
url = "https://grabagun.com/firearms/handguns/semi-automatic-handguns/glock-19-gen-5-polished-nickel-9mm-4-02-inch-barrel-15-rounds-exclusive.html"
driver.get(url)
```

I also tried chrome default profile but didn't work.

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\JHONE\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options,executable_path="C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe")
```

why the product video section not showing ?what is prevention to show the video section when using selenium?

Comment: I don't see any videos on https://grabagun.com/firearms/handguns/semi-automatic-handguns/glock-19-gen-5-polished-nickel-9mm-4-02-inch-barrel-15-rounds-exclusive.html

Comment: Rahul but here I can see and also added screenshot in my question. you can see this screenshot too https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sDUCt9vcrlRxQWSz-v8VfFEq4XwTjDW8/view?usp=share_link

Comment: I don't see it. May be its geolocation. Maybe keep it visible while debugging to see if it appears and try to inspect element there.

Comment: Rahul you have to use USA ip